# jquery on change not doing anything when trying to capture image for thumbnail

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have a video upload form like so:

```
<form action='' method='post' id="videoUpload" align = "center" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['videoID'];?>'>

        <p><label>Title</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='videoTitle' required value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['videoTitle'];}?>'></p>

        <p><label>Video</label><br />

        <input type="file" name="video" id="video" class="video" accept="video/*" required></p>

                <video controls id="video-tag"  onloadedmetadata="$(this).trigger('thumbnail_generation')">
                <source id="video-source" src="splashVideo">
                </video>

        <input type="hidden" id="thumbnail" name="thumbnail" value="" >
      

        <input type="hidden" name='videoDuration' id="videoDuration" required value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['videoDuration'];}?>'></p>

                <div id="duration" name="duration">Please choose a video</div>
                  <script src="duration.js"></script>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" /></p>

    </form>
    
    <div id="screen"></div>
```

What I have been trying to do is when a video is uploaded a thumbnail gets generated for it, for this I found something on another stack overflow question here: http://jsfiddle.net/vphyr/

So I have been trying to update this a bit so that the function is called when a video has been uploaded rather than having to click a button for it to be run.

```
var VideoSnapper = {
    
        /**
         * Capture screen as canvas
         * @param {HTMLElement} video element 
         * @param {Object} options = width of screen, height of screen, time to seek
         * @param {Function} handle function with canvas element in param
         */
        captureAsCanvas: function(video, options, handle) {
        
            // Create canvas and call handle function
            var callback = function() {
                // Create canvas
                var canvas = $('<canvas />').attr({
                    width: options.width,
                    height: options.height
                })[0];
                // Get context and draw screen on it
                canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, options.width, options.height);
               let image = canvas.toDataURL();
                document.getElementById("thumbnail").value = image;
                canvas.style.display="none";
                // Seek video back if we have previous position 
                if (prevPos) {
                    // Unbind seeked event - against loop
                    $(video).unbind('seeked');
                    // Seek video to previous position
                    video.currentTime = prevPos;
                }
                // Call handle function (because of event)
                handle.call(this, canvas);    
            }

            // If we have time in options 
            if (options.time && !isNaN(parseInt(options.time))) {
                // Save previous (current) video position
                var prevPos = video.currentTime;
                // Seek to any other time
                video.currentTime = options.time;
                // Wait for seeked event
                $(video).bind('seeked', callback);              
                return;
            }
            
            // Otherwise callback with video context - just for compatibility with calling in the seeked event
            return callback.apply(video);
        }

};

$(function() {
    
        $('video').bind('thumbnail_generation', function() {
            var video = this;
             $("#video-source").change(function() {
                var canvases = $('canvas');
                VideoSnapper.captureAsCanvas(video, { width: 160, height: 68, time: 40 }, function(canvas) {
                    $('#screen').append(canvas);                         
                    if (canvases.length == 4) 
                        canvases.eq(0).remove();     
                })
            }); 
        });
    
    });
```

However from doing: $("#video-source").change(function() { nothing is happening and I am not getting any errors

In the js example there is already pre-loaded videos so I added a script so that when a file is uploaded the video source is updated with the file like so:

```
    const videoSrc = document.querySelector("#video-source");
    const videoTag = document.querySelector("#video-tag");
    const inputTag = document.querySelector("#video");
    
    inputTag.addEventListener('change',  readVideo)
    
    function readVideo(event) {
      if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          videoSrc.src = e.target.result
          videoTag.load()
        }.bind(this)
    
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      }
    }
```

So my thinking was that I should get the function to run when the video source is updated but unfortunately I'm not having any luck, could someone help me with this? Where am I going wrong?

Edit:

So I've just got round to trying to fix this again and still struggling to get it working.

I've tried to use onloadedmeta like so:

```
$(function() {

$('video').bind('thumbnail_generation', function() {
    var video = this;
    var vid = document.getElementById("video-tag");
    vid.onloadedmetadata = function() {
   // $('#capture').click(function() {
        var canvases = $('canvas');
        VideoSnapper.captureAsCanvas(video, { width: 160, height: 68, time: 40 }, function(canvas) {
            $('#screen').append(canvas);                         
            if (canvases.length == 4) 
                canvases.eq(0).remove();     
        })
   // });
    }
});
```

});

However with this nothing happens, and I have now tried to do what Louys suggested and use a mutation observer like so:

```
$(function() {
    
        $('video').bind('thumbnail_generation', function() {
            var video = this;
            var img = document.querySelector("#video-tag video"),
            observer = new MutationObserver((changes) => {
            changes.forEach(change => {
            if(change.attributeName.includes('src')){
            console.dir(img.src);
                var canvases = $('canvas');
                VideoSnapper.captureAsCanvas(video, { width: 160, height: 68, time: 40 }, function(canvas) {
                    $('#screen').append(canvas);                         
                    if (canvases.length == 4) 
                        canvases.eq(0).remove();     
                })
        }
        });
});
        });
        observer.observe(img, {attributes : true});
    });
```

With this, however, I am getting the error:
add-videos.php:159 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

I'm not really sure what this error means. Am I on the right track? Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when an alteration to the element's value is committed by the user.* [MDN - change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) -- Maybe look for *mutation observer*... to listen to `src` attribute change.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you, I'll look into that

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette could you have a look at what I've added to my question if you get the chance please?

Comment: Parameter 1 is `img`. The error is saying that `img` is not a DOM node. I guess it is `undefined` because you defined it inside the `thumbnail_generation` event handler and the `observer.observe()` call is outside. `img` looks wrong anyway. I think it should be `document.querySelector("#video-source")` because that is the "node" having the `src` attribute.

Comment: I've change the query selector to what you have suggested but I am still getting the same error, would you mind giving an example of how it should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles upon the same issue I had, all I actually had to change it to was:

```
$(function() {

$('video').bind('thumbnail_generation', function() {
    let video = this;
        let canvases = $('canvas');
        VideoSnapper.captureAsCanvas(video, { width: 160, height: 68, time: 40 }, function(canvas) {
            $('#screen').append(canvas);                         
            if (canvases.length == 4) 
                canvases.eq(0).remove();     
        })
});

});
```

Turned out I had been overthinking and the reason why nothing had been happening is by the time this script had been reached, the video source had already been changed so there was no change for it to listen at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I just can't reproduce your issue... So here are a couple hints about debugging it yourself:

The `src` change that you want to detect is on the `<source>` element.

```
<video controls id="video-tag"  onloadedmetadata="$(this).trigger('thumbnail_generation')">
  <source id="video-source" src="splashVideo">
</video>
```

Now, to debug the `observe()` function, put some console logs everywhere you can to be able to know where it possibly stucks:

```
$(function() {

  $('video').on('thumbnail_generation', function() {
  
    console.log("thumbnail_generation event fired.")
  
    var video = this;
    var img = document.querySelector("#video-source");
    
    console.log("This is img:", img) // Should output : "This is img:" "<source id='video-source' src='splashVideo'>"
    
    var observer = new MutationObserver((changes) => {
    
      console.log("A change occurred")
    
      changes.forEach(change => {
      
        console.log("change object:", change) // Should ouput all change objects.
      
        if(change.type === "attributes" && change.attributeName === "src"){
        
          console.log(img.src);  // Should output the new src value
          
          // I can't tell about the rest...
          var canvases = $('canvas');
          VideoSnapper.captureAsCanvas(video, { width: 160, height: 68, time: 40 }, function(canvas) {
            $('#screen').append(canvas);                         
            if (canvases.length == 4) 
            canvases.eq(0).remove();     
          })
          
        }
      });
    });
    
    // Call the observe() function here
    observer.observe(img, {attributes : true});
    
  });
  
});
```

Also, jQuery [.bind()](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) is deprecated since jQuery 3.0... So even if it still works, I suggest you to start using the [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead.

Comment: That's really helpful thank you, sorry I wasn't meaning for you to do it for me, think I maybe worded my comment badly there, thank you for this though, really appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem! I is just a bit harder for me when I cannot test my answer... ;) I think you are on the right path.

Comment: Yeah haha. Looking at it now, it is supposed:
 var vid = document.querySelector("#video-source", video); but what I am actually getting in the console log is: 

This is vid: <source id=​"video-source" src=​"data:​video/​mp4;​base64,AAAAI…hAAAAAQAAAABMYXZmNTguMzMuMTAw">​.

So at this point the video source has actually already changed so I'm going to have to play about with this a bit more

Comment: Actually just realised I don't need all the on change events going on, thank you for your help I have got it working now